# When I use the WindowBuilder preview function, the code appears as it should, but not when I press "run"

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

When I use the WindowBuilder preview, the code appears as it should, but when I run the program, it just brings up a blank frame.  It looks fine in the preview, but as soon as I run it, it just brings up a blank frame.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel teamSelect;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocation(new Point(100, 50));
                frame.setSize(1800, 900);
                frame.setTitle("Hockey");

                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Frame() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    teamSelect = new JPanel();
    teamSelect.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(teamSelect);
    teamSelect.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

    JPanel divisionGrid = new JPanel();
    teamSelect.add(divisionGrid, "name_3885325667274");
    divisionGrid.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 0, 0));

    JPanel metroDivision = new JPanel();
    divisionGrid.add(metroDivision);
    metroDivision.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JLabel lblMetropolitanDivision = new JLabel("Metropolitan Division");
    lblMetropolitanDivision.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblMetropolitanDivision.setFont(new Font("Eras Bold ITC", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    metroDivision.add(lblMetropolitanDivision, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JPanel atlanticDivision = new JPanel();
    divisionGrid.add(atlanticDivision);
    atlanticDivision.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JLabel lblAtlanticDivision = new JLabel("Atlantic Division");
    lblAtlanticDivision.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblAtlanticDivision.setFont(new Font("Eras Bold ITC", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    atlanticDivision.add(lblAtlanticDivision, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JPanel centralDivision = new JPanel();
    divisionGrid.add(centralDivision);
    centralDivision.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Central Division");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Eras Bold ITC", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    centralDivision.add(lblNewLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JPanel pacificDivision = new JPanel();
    divisionGrid.add(pacificDivision);
    pacificDivision.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Pacific Division");
    lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Eras Bold ITC", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    lblNewLabel_1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    pacificDivision.add(lblNewLabel_1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
new JFrame();
```

by

```
new Frame();
```

And call `pack()` before `setVisible(true)`.

Note that just adding a `System.out.println()` or using the debugger to step through your code would have allowed you to find this simple mistake. A debugger is a wonderful tool. use it.

Comment: To the downvoter: care to explain your downvote? I think you have not read the question carefully.